# how to import PlaygroundSupport on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import

On Xcode, I get no such module 'playgroundsupport' when importing playgroundsupport.
On Playgrounds, "import playground" works on my MacBook.

I am in the middle of putting some sound effects like do, re, mi, fa...
on my small app game.